# Existence of Initial Object implies Existence of Terminal Object?

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

Consider an initial object always exists in a category. Reversing all arrows now. Does this guarantee the existence of terminal objects in that category?

Comment: No it guarantees that the opposite category will have a terminal object. But your average category isn't isomorphic to its opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help you understand what is going on, consider the finite category $\mathcal I$ consisting of three objects $X, Y, Z$ and two non-identity arrows $f\colon Y\to X$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$. Then the initial object of $\mathcal I$ is $Y$.  Then $Y$ is the terminal object in the opposite category (ie reversing all arrows) $\mathcal I^{op}$ since $f^{op}\colon X\to Y$ and $g^{op}\colon Z\to Y$.

So, yes, an initial object becomes the terminal object in the opposite category. This is the same as saying that initial and terminal are dual concepts.

I think user18921 said "No" because he took your "that category" to mean the original non-opposite category that you started with. But as we can see by looking at $\mathcal I$, it does not have a terminal object even though it has an initial object $Y$. The dual to this is that $\mathcal I^{op}$ does not have an initial object even though it has a terminal object $Y$.

Comment: But I don't mean the opposite category - sure in the opposite category terminal objects trivially exist since they are the same as the initial objects in the original category...

Comment: @Freeze_S Well, then. Shouldn't the above example show you why the existence of an initial doesn't imply the existence of a terminal?

Comment: Can u point out which categories $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ you're considering as well as which functor $\mathrm{U}:\mathbf{D}\to\mathbf{C}$ (I guess the identity functor)

Comment: @Freeze_S Maybe I am misunderstanding your question. This is the way I understand it. You started with a category with an initial object $\mathcal I$. Then you reversed all the arrows. This is the definition of what $\mathcal I^{op}$ is. Then if you mean $\mathcal I$ for what you said "that category", $\mathcal I$ does not have a terminal object, you can check on hom-sets. Why are you asking for a functor?

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry I meant an object satisfying the universal property once as an initial morphism once as a terminal morphism (see wiki universal property)

Comment: @Freeze_S If you are given a functor $F\colon \mathcal C\to \mathcal D$, then an initial morphism of $D\in\mathcal D$ is just an initial object in the comma category $D\downarrow F$ and the terminal morphism of $D$ is the terminal object of $F\downarrow D$. What category are you taking the dual of?

Comment: @Freeze_S Could you rephrase the above question or remove it until you feel confident in the basic definitions you are referring to?

Comment: Yes I meant  this but I'll close it better...

Comment: Is it possible to inactivate it?